# Прозрачный фон SimpleExoPlayerView

Tags: android, exoplayer

Как сделать прозрачный фон для `SimpleExoPlayerView` плеера `ExoPlayer`. Если указать любой другой непрозрачный фон, то нормально, а если указать transparent, то фон черный получается.

Comment: Похоже никто не сталкивался с таким?

Comment: @null попробуйте